# Is this javascript Code a security risk

Tags: javascript

I want to make a flash message on a static html page. I plan to use the following code and I wonder if it can be a security risk?

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

  
  var results = parseURL(window.location.href);
 
  if (results['info']) {
 
  $("#flash").html(urldecode(results['info']));
  $("#flash").addClass("alert-info");
  $("#flash").removeClass("hidden");
 }
 


});

function urldecode(str) {
   return decodeURIComponent((str+'').replace(/\+/g, '%20'));
}

function parseURL(url) {

var parser = document.createElement('a'),
 searchObject = {},
 queries, split, i;

// Let the browser do the work
parser.href = url;

// Convert query string to object
queries = parser.search.replace(/^\?/, '').split('&');
for( i = 0; i < queries.length; i++ ) {
 split = queries[i].split('=');
 searchObject[split[0]] = split[1];
}

return searchObject;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="flash" class="alert hidden" role="alert"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, that's probably a security risk assuming there is something on that domain worth attacking. You should have no problem injecting JavaScript in the `info` parameter for an XSS attack.

As a general rule, it's best to never output HTML from a query string on the page.

To that end, you could replace the `.html` method:

```
$("#flash").html(urldecode(results['info']));
```

with the `.text` method:

```
$("#flash").text(urldecode(results['info']));
```

Answer (score 1):

You're taking data from the URL and putting it in the page as HTML.

The first risk is cross-site scripting, if a malicious site provides a crafted link to legitimate users with data (e.g. cookies) on your domain, the attacker's code could read it and send it to their own servers.

That can be compounded if the users can access APIs on your domain, the injected code could send requests in their name.

So, yeah, try not to insert URL-extracted data as HTML. Display it as a string and you'll be safe (except from social engineering).

Comment: yes thanks  to Alexander and Paulpro the XSS-Part is now clear can you explain your thought on social enginieering a little bit?

Comment: Well, an attacker could make any message appear on *your* website. Including a message that tells the user to do something harmful and if they trust your website they might believe it. Or it could be something offensive that makes them hate you, or some prank that makes them call tech support with weird questions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is an issue. You are parsing the query string for `?info=` or `&info=` and then taking everything after that and inserting it directly into the page as HTML.

If I make a website that puts your in a hidden iframe like `<iframe src="//yoursite.com/?info=&lt;script&gt;// anything;" />`

I can make arbitrary Javascript run on your page that has access to the user visiting my website's cookies on your website. That means I can make them do stuff on your website without them knowing, or send their cookies to my server so I can hijack their session.